# Mysql code adapted to mysqli code leaves page blanc

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a problem. My first code (MYSQL) is giving me the latest 5 rows from the table chat.
My second code (MYSQLi) doesn't return anything, leaves the page blanc, and gives me no error messages.

Code 1:

```
$messages = array ();
$sql = mysql_query("select * from users ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 5");
while( $results = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) )
{
    array_unshift( $messages, $results);
}
```

Code 2:

```
$messages = array ();
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from users ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 5");
while( $results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql) )
{
    array_unshift( $messages, $results);
}
```

I think the code is fully correct. But still, as I said, I don't get any output, just a blanc page.
Can anyone help me? I don't like PDO, so looking for procedural options.

Comment: You need to learn about the very important concept of error reporting. No page would give you an error message unless you'd explicitly ask it to

Comment: Have you checked that the database connection `$con` is good? Did you check for errors when you created the connection? There's nothing in the code to produce any output, so I'm not sure why you are surprised you get a blank page.

Comment: You can use PDO either with procedural or OO techniques by the way - preferring procedural is not a reason to avoid PDO.

Comment: Did you check to see whether the query actually executed properly? What is in `$sql` when you display it while you're debugging?